# ASP.NET MVC finding the current username in a custom action filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I am creating a custom action filter for asp.net MVC.

In the `OnActionExecuting()` method.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    string userName =  ?????// how can I get this?
}
```

I need to find out the current users name (I am using forms authentication)

In the controller I can simply just do `User.Identity.Name`

Is there a way to get the users name in the ActionFilter?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
string userName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

And if you wanted to check if there is an authenticated user first:

```
string userName = null;
if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    userName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Comment: Well that was incredibly easy, not sure why I has such a hard time finding it. Thank you once again Darin!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov How to get UserId instead of name? In controller action, I can simply use `User.Identity.GetUserId();`